# Login Issue When a Device Joins Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am completely new to Azure Active Directory. I have invited a Microsoft account to my Azure AD and accepted the invitation. However, when I am joining my computer to Azure Active Directory, the login isn't correct. I have no idea why because I can connect with Microsoft using the same login.

I tried to delete and reinvite the user several times in case of a desynchronized password. But that was useless. Even with a Google account, I have the same issue. I have also tried with the Global Administrator of Azure AD, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have also tried with the Global Administrator of Azure AD, but that didn't change anything.

`Azure AD Guest` accounts can't connect to `Azure VMs` enabled `VMs` using `Azure AD` authentication.

If you invite any `Guest` users into `Azure AD` they are synchronized into `Azure AD Domain Services`, but the Guest user passwords are not stored in `Azure AD`.

For logging into `Azure VMs`, users' passwords must be stored in `NTLM/Kerberos`, but `Guest` users' passwords are not stored in `NTLM/Kerberos`, so those users can't sign in or join computers.

Refer: [Azure AD Guest`accounts can't connect to`Azure VMs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/faqs#can-guest-users-be-invited-to-my-directory-use-microsoft-entra-domain-services-)